# Does “if” have implicit access to a class’s special methods even when they are not directly called?

Tags: python, oop, if-statement, boolean, magic-methods

I don’t understand how the code in the for loop knows whether the instance of the class is truthy or not. My understanding is probably faulty but what I think is happening is this: the call to bool calls the altered special method **bool** which has been modified to use the len built in on the instance. But outside of the class, when we get to the for loop and the if conditional I don’t know how “if” knows whether the order is truthy unless it is calling the special method **bool**(behind the scenes).

I apologise if this is not the forum for such a question but I don’t know enough of the required terminology to find an answer to this on google or a good book to get my head around OOP with a python bias.

**Code**

```
class Order:
    def __init__(self, cart, customer):
        self.cart = list(cart)
        self.customer = customer

   # def __bool__(self):
          #print("\'__bool__ got called\'")
          #return len(self.cart) > 0
        
order1 = Order(['banana', 'apple', 'mango'], 'Real Python')
order2 = Order([], 'Python')


for order in [order1, order2]:
    if order:
        print(f"{order.customer}'s order is processing...")
    else:
        print(f"Empty order for customer {order.customer}")


print(bool(order2))
```

Comment: It might be cleaner to prevent an `Order` instance from being created with an empty cart.

Comment: Certainly yes, this is some code that I found in a tutorial online that has illustrated one of the many things I don’t understand about Objects, all the books I have seem to gloss over objects once they have shown you how to make a basic one and call a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer [Python3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__bool__#object.__bool__)

In short, your object's base class has a `__bool__` function that can be implemented to define truthfulness.
If it's not defined on the type, then the base class implementation will be called.
It functions as you said, by calling `__len__`.

If neither `__bool__` nor `__len__` are defined, all the class objects are considered true.

Edit to my answer with @chepner's contribution from the comments:

In order to evaluate bool(Order()), Python tries to:

1. find a definition of `Order.__bool__`,
2. then a definition of `__bool__` for some parent class.
3. If it still hasn't found one, it looks for `Order.__len__`,
4. then for a parent that defines `__len__`.
5. If none of those are found, then `bool(Order())` simply returns `True`.

Comment: I’m trying to understand what some of this means, can I just check?  My objects base class is the one I have defined? I don’t understand the “if it’s not defined on the type” - does that mean that when the for loop code is “if order: “ and that instantiation (is that what you mean by ‘type’?) as there is no explicit call to bool in that type/instance the if will then look to the base class for that instance/type and see if there is a method there, if it finds none it will return True?

Comment: The base class is (implicitly) `object`, because you didn't specify a base class for `Order`. (Compare with something like `class Order(Foo)`, where some other class `Foo` would be the base class of `Order`.) In order to evaluate `bool(Order())`, Python first tries to find a definition of `Order.__bool__`, then a definition of `__bool__` for some parent class. If it still hasn't found one, it looks for `Order.__len__`, then for a parent that defines `__len__`. If *none* of those are found, then `bool(Order())` simply returns `True`.